# How to evaluate a lambda function for many values in place?

Tags: python

I'd like to draw a periodic Heaviside function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(-2,2,10)

def periodic_function(func, period, offset):
    return lambda x: func( ((x - offset) % period ) + offset )

def f(x,xm):   
    return 1 * (x > xm)

wave = periodic_function(f,4,2)

plt.plot(x,wave)
plt.show()
```

But the problem is that `wave` only evaluates `f` for one value of `x`. Thus the final `plt.show()` is not dimensionally sound as I have 10 values of `x` with only 1 value of evaluated `f`. How can I fix that?

Comment: How about [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)?

Comment: It seems you only give 1 argument to f/func in periodic_function when you create the lambda.

Comment: @jaaq: Yes, and I've no idea what's the way to pass the whole range of `x` to it.

Comment: @Pinton what should the function f do?

Comment: @jaaq: It is just a step function known as Heaviside function. It jumps up at `x=xm`.

Comment: @Pinton and what is xm supposed to be?

Comment: @jaaq: That is just a constant number. Pick whatever you want.

Comment: updated my answer. It really boils down how you want to precalculate your list of y values for the plot. You can do that however you like. If you want shorter code, maybe post to codegolf.stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

The mathplotlib.pyplot.plot function expects a list of values x and a list of values y of the same length. It's probably easiest if you precaclulate y:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 10)

heaviside_step_point = 0  # Example value


def periodic_function(func, period, offset):
    return lambda x: func(((x - offset) % period) + offset)


def get_heaviside_step_function(xm):
    return lambda x: int(x > xm)


f = periodic_function(get_heaviside_step_function(heaviside_step_point), 4, 2)

y = np.array([f(a) for a in x])

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Now you can adjust the periodic function so that it accepts the current x and simply iterate over the values you want to plot.

HTH

Comment: How would I know which value of the range is the current one to be passed to the periodic function?

Comment: the plot function iterates through both lists. So for x it's first value will be `-2`, then it looks up the first value for y which will be equal to the result of `periodic_function(f,4,2,-2)` and then it will plot the first point at `[x==-2, y==periodic_function(f,4,2,-2)]`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but more just like a comment I suppose. Don't you think it would be a much better approach to post a compilable snippet which explicitly solves the OP's problem?

Comment: I'd love to, but I have not been able to identify the use of the function `f`. Furthermore the question actually seems to be about how to pass parameters to the pyplot.plt function.

Comment: I guess `f` just generates a unit heaviside function, where the `xm` is its step point. The OP has to confirm that though.

Comment: wouldn't a heaviside step function just be `return 1 if x > 0 else 0`?

Comment: I guess so. One would define that in many ways. In particular, I think the OP's one is a variant which is pretty suitable for vectorized solutions.

Comment: Did you successfully run your code? It tells me `xm` is not defined! `;-)`

Comment: The interpreter says that `xm` is not defined.

Comment: yes sorry of course you have to pass the heaviside_step_point variable. copy paste error on my side

Comment: Now we have `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (3,)`.

Comment: sorry it has been a while since I last worked on numpy. this code kind of works now? I really don't know what results you expect but I guess it does what you want in a programmatic sense.